# Get comma separated values from a table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, table structures as below.

```
Table: items
Id   item_name     item_ids
1    pens          10,11,12,13
2    books         20, 30
3    computer      50, 60, 80

Another table : activities

Id  activity_id
1   10
2   11
3   20
4   60
```

So Now I want to get item_ids from items table which are not present in activities table using **JOINS** only. **No Subquery**. Lets say I want to retrieve item_ids of pens those are not in activities table. Ex For pens, item_ids are 10, 11,12,13. My result should be 12 and 13.

Comment: You should normalize your items table.  Having a comma separated list of IDs in a column is not good practice.

Comment: @Rick S. Yes it's not good practice, but the requirement is that :(

Comment: @ jpw. Sorry for the late reply. Expected output id's are 12, 13. But your query outputs 20 and 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query uses some string manipulation and extracts the individual items from the `item_ids` using a numbers table (created inline as a derived table). Note that it only handles up to 9 items in the comma separated list, but if you expect more just add more numbers to the derived table.

```
SELECT 
    items.id,
    items.item_name,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(items.item_ids, ',', numbers.n),
            ',',
            - 1) item_ids
FROM
    (SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) numbers
        INNER JOIN
    items ON CHAR_LENGTH(items.item_ids) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(items.item_ids, ',', '')) >= numbers.n - 1
        LEFT JOIN
    activities a ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(items.item_ids, ',', numbers.n),
            ',',
            - 1) = a.activity_id
WHERE
    item_name = 'Pens'
        AND activity_id IS NULL
;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3387/4)

Result:

```
| Id | item_name | item_ids |
|----|-----------|----------|
|  1 |      pens |       12 |
|  1 |      pens |       13 |
```